# IntelliJ IDEA: temporarily replace JAR with local classes

Tags: intellij-idea

The gradle build script for the project is pulling a JAR file as a dependency, let's call it "LibX". I have the LibX source locally and would like to make some changes to the code and test my project against those changes.

I am able to add the local classes as a library in the project structure settings, and add these to the test module, and I can drag this to the top of the list of dependencies for the test module. However, changes I'm making to LibX are not being reflected (I'm recompiling) when I run tests.

What am I missing? I'm also open to the possibility that this is totally the wrong workflow. Basically, I'd like to be able to modify code in a dependency and test, without having to push changes made to the dependency, and pull a new snapshot build.